# Recyclerview onCreateViewHolder not calling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

set `LayoutManager` and `Adapter`

```
mLayoutManager = new WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(getContext());
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

add item

```
private void addItem(LiveChatData data) {
    if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter.getItems() != null) {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.what = HANDLER_REFRESH_LIST_ADD_CONTENT;
        message.obj = data;
        chatMessageHandler.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

`HANDLER_REFRESH_LIST_ADD_CONTENT` in process

```
public void addItem(LiveChatData item) {
    if (item == null) return;
    try {
        mItems.add(item);
        notifyContentItemInserted(mItems.size() - 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtils.w(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

It usually works. Sometimes `onCreateViewHolder` not calling so `RecyclerView` is empty.

but, view in Drag and drop to normal operation.

my `RecyclerView XML` tree is

> Coordinatorlayout/LinearLayout(BottomSheet)/RelativeLayout/Recyclerview

View tree is

> MainActivity/Fragment/FragmentPager/Fragment

Why does not call `onCreateViewHoler` sometime?

Comment: what purpose of your first `addItem(LiveChatData data)`

Comment: data from WebSocket, parse and convert data

Comment: adapter getCount() may be 0.

Comment: no, getCount is normality, 1 add item is plus 1 Count

Comment: onCreateViewHolder is only called when a new view is called. if your new item is out of the screen, new view will not be called. if you scroll to new item, the existing view is reused and only onBindViewHolder is called.

Comment: I'm check it out in debug mode. but, onBindViewHolder is not call.